# Revision control -- see diffs of Title

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, revisions-list, diff

I have noticed that on Stack Overflow you can now see diffs of the different revisions side-by-side by clicking one of the buttons next to the revision.

My gripe with that is that it does not show changes to the title side by side.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/7393045/revisions

Can we make it so it also shows changes to the title in a diff?

Comment: er.. breaking the title into side-by-side would cause a ton of scrolling, because the title is so large

Comment: @JeffAtwood maybe try to cut it to show only the diff area of the title like `...Title...`, or make the font smaller for the title when in diff mode.

Comment: @JeffAtood maybe have the title exandable and smaller font to see previous iterations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright, fair enough; the side-by-side HTML diff view will also show the title diff as a side-by-side in the next build.

However, we only show the "switch diff view" controls when there's an edit to the post body (otherwise they just take up space), so you won't get the side-by-side title diff if the edit changed *only* the title.

Comment: it did not seem to take affect in the link in the OP.

Comment: Read my post. "in the next build"

Comment: Then it should not be labeled [meta-tag:status-completed], no? At least not until it is actually done. (I could be wrong on that fact)

Comment: If a title has been edited in several places, the one-line diff can be very difficult to read. It would be good to have the option always available.