# Allow side-by-side comparison of edited question titles

Tags: feature-request, bug, revisions-list, diff

On a question's revision page, you can select between 3 diff modes:

> [image: diff mode]

This generally works fine for edits to the question body, but does not work for the question title. E.g. in the ***side-by-side markdown*** mode, the title comparison appeared similar to ***inline*** mode:

> [image: side-by-side-markdown]

Moreover, if only the title was changed, the selectable diff-mode buttons are not even visible. E.g. (no buttons on the top):

> [image: only-title]

I found [the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106038/339911) for the old question: [Revision control -- see diffs of Title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105989/339911), but I don't agree with it. I don't think that such buttons only take up space, they can be really useful.

So, my request is to have title changes display properly in ***side-by-side markdown*** diff-mode, and to have the side-by-side option be available if only the question's title has been changed.

Comment: Titles cannot have markdown. Only plain text. There is no point in a side-by-side markdown diff more for title changes.

Comment: @Oded: I was thinking the same thing, except that titles *can* have MathJax on some sites.

Comment: @Oded ***side-by-side markdown*** should be still ***side-by-side***, not ***inline***.

Comment: @Oded It doesn't really matter if the titles can't have markdown, though, they can still be edited, and there's still just as much value in showing the old vs. the new rather than having the changes shown inline.